# Can't convert undefined to object (object.keys() function)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I am trying to iterate through the redux store and render all objects present. In an attempt to create an array of the objects I encounter the following error

[image]

The relevant code snippet:

```
class VictoryChartComp extends React.Component{
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  //this.ChartsArray = [];
  this.ChartsArray = Object.keys(this.props.newcharts).map(function (key) {
    if (this.props.newcharts.type == 'victory') {
    var item = this.props.newcharts[key];
    return item;
  }
}); 
}
```

The whole code can be found here: https://codesandbox.io/s/xr5wk9v35o

I have also tried to declare 'this.ChartsArray' (commented line) but the problem still exists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First check this.props.newcharts whether this variable has value or not,

Comment: Can't run your sandbox. Some firebase error - `No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp()`

Comment: Can you check this line in the ```Recharts.js``` file:

```import { render } from 'react-dom';
```

why you're using ```render``` this way?

Comment: if you uncomment out the firebase initializing app in 'index.js' (line 23) should work.

Comment: @salman.zare It's completely okay to use `render` that way

Comment: First: May I know why `VictoryChartComp` is a class-based component since you're neither using state nor life-cycle hooks methods? Second: What values are you passing as `this.props.newcharts`? BTW your sandbox is giving some firebase error.

Comment: @Munna Hmm it looks like it is coming back as undefined. I believe I am pulling the data from firebase and storing it in the store correctly. Is there a reason why it might be undefined?

Comment: why have you commented out `mapStateToProps` ?

Comment: your code is full of typos I guess... it is `newcharts` somewhere, and `newCharts` else where... props name `chart` and `charts` etc.

Comment: @Dane Yes there were a few places that a mismatch was present and I have corrected it.

Comment: The error is no longer present but I am not able to access the required child node because there are Firebase generated keys at intermediate levels (hence props.newCharts is undefined). Is there a way for me to access the contents of the child without knowing the parent-key?

Comment: yes. you can iterate through the keys and push their children onto a new array

Answer (score 0):

I tested this out on your sandbox and the fix for the error is of course to validate that `this.props.newcharts` is not `null` or `undefined`. From `VictoryChartComp.js`

```
this.ChartsArray = this.props.newcharts
  ? Object.keys(this.props.newcharts).map(function(key) {
    if (this.props.newcharts.type === "victory") {
      var item = this.props.newcharts[key];
        return item;
      }
    })
  : [];
```

This will allow `ChartsArray` to not be undefined if `this.props.newCharts` is `null`.

Even though this solves the console error and allows the component to render it comes out blank - because newCharts is `undefined` in my execution. I'm not sure if that is what you actually want. You might want to make `newCharts` required.